# IPv6 Connectivity Issue - Cannot connect to IPv6 sites intermittently

Tags: networking, ipv6

I've configured an ISATAP router to enable me to connect to IPv6 sites. The interesting thing is that it sometimes works and sometimes does not and I do not know where the problem lies. Can anybody help me fix this connectivity issue?

As a start I'm pasting what I think might be helpful here.

Using netsh it shows something like this:

```
Router Name            : isatap.sjtu.edu.cn
Use Relay              : default
Resolution Interval    : default
netsh interface ipv6 isatap>
```

Ping isatap.sjtu.edu.cn shows:

```
Pinging isatap.sjtu.edu.cn [202.112.26.246] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 202.112.26.246: bytes=32 time=74ms TTL=44
Reply from 202.112.26.246: bytes=32 time=74ms TTL=44
Reply from 202.112.26.246: bytes=32 time=74ms TTL=44
Reply from 202.112.26.246: bytes=32 time=74ms TTL=44
```

IPConfig output:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : resnet.ust.hk
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:8f59:a0c7:b:98b5:560d:8ec7:ec11
   Site-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fec0::b:98b5:560d:8ec7:ec11%1
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2002:8f59:a0c7:b:5d27:6f33:cbb3:fec9
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::98b5:560d:8ec7:ec11%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 143.89.160.16
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 143.89.163.254

Tunnel adapter isatap.resnet.ust.hk:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Ping ipv6.google.com:

```
Ping request could not find host ipv6.google.com. Please check the name and try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any mention of IPv6 DNS.  Your pings are being sent over IPv4.

To ping the IPv6 way:

> ping -6 www.kame.net